# Authenticated API access to Firebase via REST API

Tags: google-app-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, service-accounts

This is surprisingly excruciating. There's no documentation whatsoever for the new Firebase + Python. So I'm trying to use the REST API, which needs a special kind of authentication.

[image]
As you can see, they say it could be the **app's secret** (nowhere to be found in the new console) or the **authentication token** (which is not documented for python). If I click the *REST authentication documentation* I get a Java example.

I've downloaded the JSON Key file for the service account, and tried to apply pieces of code found in other places, unfortunately in vain.

Can anyone provide a hint on how to proceed with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an access token from the service account JSON key file using the [Google API Python client library](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/get_started), and then add it to the headers of your request.

Here's an example of how to do it with [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import requests
import json
import httplib2

scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
]

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    '/pathto/json_file.json', scopes)

headers = {"content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"}
headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + credentials.get_access_token().access_token

firebase_url = "https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/fireblog/users/alanisawesome/name.json"

data = {
    "name": "Alan Turing",
    "birthday": "June 23, 1912"}

requests.put(firebase_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data).encode("utf-8"))
```

You can install the google python api client library using pip:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Comment: I get error 403 Permission Denied when I try to access firebase database. According to the docs it should work. My question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810233 . I appreciate your help